# Is minimised cross-validated error equivalent to maximised cross-validated accuracy?

Tags: r, classification, cart, accuracy, rpart

I'm running a classification tree using the function rpart. Usually, I choose the tree that minimises the cross-validation error. I was wondering, since error-rate is normally defined as 1-Accuracy. Is this the same than choosing the tree that maximises cross-validated accuracy? Thank you!

Comment: I think you may have answered your own question.

Comment: Yes. filler text

Comment: Alright :-) Thanks anyway for the confirmation!